# Round off whole number in C

Tags: c, rounding

I have a number (00-59) in an int and i would like to round it off to 5, for example 06 would be 5 and 08 would be 10. Oh and 07 would also be 10. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Would [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/ceil/) help? How about writing a small for loop/if statement thingy to calculate the modulus and go about it from there on?

Comment: 7->10 would be a ceil operation, but that'd mean 6 becomes 10 as well. 7.5 would be the lowest number that should become 10 when rounded to the nearest 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
int round_5(int num)
{
   int t1;
   t1= num%5;
   if(t1>=2)
      num+=(5-t1);
   else
      num-=t1;
   return num;
}


main()
{
   int num = 57;
   num = round_5(num);
   printf("%d",num);
   return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to code your own round function, here is something that should work:

```
int round(int number, int round_by)
{
    int whole = number / round_by;
    char superior = ((number % round_by) >= (round_by / 2)) ? 1 : 0;
    return (whole + superior) * round_by;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", round(6, 5)); // 5
    printf("%d\n", round(7, 5)); // 10
    printf("%d\n", round(8, 5)); // 10
    printf("%d\n", round(33, 10)); // 30
    printf("%d\n", round(33, 5)); // 35
}
```

You can replace 5 by every number you want.

Comment: You missed a `?` in your ternary, and that's just re-doing `(round(a / by) * by)`, doesn't answer OP's need for 7->10

Comment: @Eregrith Thanks, I edited my answer, now for 7 it's 10 too, even if I don't understand why it should be ten... x)

Comment: I'm programming a word-clock that only has 5 minute resolution, so i'd rather have it round up than down

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula

```
rounded = (number / 5) * 5;
if ((number % 5) > 1)
  rounded += 5;
```

Comment: This code doesn't even come close to working correctly. Your code produces this result: 7 -> 6, 8 -> 6, 9 -> 6. You might want to test it first before posting a solution here.

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot the important part `* 5`. That's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't C specific but the idea works the same:

```
func roundToNearest(num someNumber, num roundToNearest)
{
    return (round(someNumber / roundToNearest) * roundToNearest);
}
```

This is just pseudocode of course, in the case of C you'll need to be casting to singles to get anything useful out of it.

In the case of c, round comes from `math.h`

Comment: Except that for the case of 07 will round(1.4) => 1 => 5 and not 10 as OP asked.

Comment: OP has his question wrong, 7->10 would be a ceil operation, but that'd mean 6 becomes 10 as well. 7.5 would be the lowest number that should  become 10 when rounded to the nearest 5.

Comment: OP has his question the way he wants, doesn't he? It's his call and he never mentioned either ceil or floor; he said round.

Comment: Right - 7 to the nearest 5 is not 10, it's 5.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't say he wanted the nearest either.

Comment: `round` by definition is to the nearest unless you specify a direction. You can either round up, round down, or round to the nearest. The numbers OP gave don't fit either of those, so either his math is completely off or he has failed to adequately explain what he wants.

Comment: Welcome to SO where people fail to explain their needs as real life customers :D !

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to delve into the floating-point realm, you can do something like this:

```
int rounded = (int)(round((float)input / 5) * 5);
```

Make sure you `#include <math.h>`.  See [this ideone example](http://ideone.com/BIMwwv).

Comment: Except that for the case of 07 will round(1.4) => 1 => 5 and not 10 as OP asked.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of a bizarre requirement, as 7 is closer to 5 than 10.  But if that is the requirement, then one could replace `input` with `(input + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about a look up table

int minutes [60] = { 0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10, ... };

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
unsigned int round5(unsigned int n)
{
    return ((n + 2) / 5) * 5;
}
```

(Say `+ 3` if you want to round 7 up, though this would seem unnatural.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
//no -> number  ro -> round off to
//ro = 5 in your case
int no, ro;
if(no%ro >= 2)
    no = ((no/ro)+1)*ro;
else
    no = (no/ro)*ro;
```

Hope it helps !!